# DataLabel-plugin Value changes in X and Y Data Structure

Tags: angular, chart.js, ng2-charts

I used the Data label plugin to show Y value only, but as data structure attached below to show x and y axis

```
public barChartData:any ={
 
    datasets: [
      {
      data: [{x:'Sales', y:20}, {x:'Revenue', y:10}],
      label:"point 1",
      backgroundColor:'rgba(238, 83, 79, 1)'

      },
      {
        data: [{x:'Sales', y:40}, {x:'Revenue', y:40}],
       label: "point 2"
  
      }
  ] 
  
  };
```

[image: The Result Image for using these data structure]
These the data structure for chart, Is any way to show Y-value  without changing the data Structure to Y value only in data.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Formatter Function inside options of datalabels

```
 datalabels: {
    formatter:(value, context) => {
      return value.y
    },
```